# I want to sort time strings

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I have an array of time in string format.
For Ex : a = ["10:00 AM", "12:00 AM", "03:00 PM", "01:00 PM"]

I want to sort this string as we sort it in the date format.

I tried moment but couldn't succeed

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var times = ["10:00 AM", "12:00 AM", "03:00 PM", "01:00 PM"];

times.sort(function (timeA, timeB) {
  return new Date('1970/01/01 ' + timeA) - new Date('1970/01/01 ' + timeB);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use moment.js try something like this:

```
a.sort((firstEl, secondEl) => {
    return moment(firstEl, "HH:MM a").isBefore(moment(secondEl, "HH:MM a"));
}
```